# RCA in to a Microphone Input

Tags: sound-design, stereo, amplifier

I am trying to use a TV as an audio source on an amp.  The amp only has 2 sets of RCA inputs while the other 3 inputs are mic jacks.  The mic hacks have a switch over them that selects between - "line" "phantom" "mic".  When I go from my rca to mic converter and plug it in the signal seems to only get the background sounds and not the full signal.  Is there something else I need to do or use to make this setup work?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I am already using the two sets of rca inputs for other sources.

Comment: Can you put back this information into your post please? You just have to use the edit button. Thx

Comment: i assume that when you say "mic jacks" you mean XLR connections. I also reckon that there's a phantom switch above them, what you want is to have this switched to "line" . Now if this is an xlr connection i have to assume that you have some sort of adapter which you call "converter"? so i think we are on the same page. Well from the moment you connect the rca connection to the xlr connection assuming(again) that all the converters/adapters and cables are in good condition you should have a connection.. for one channel. Actually a photo of the back of the amp would help so much! Cause you don't

Answer (score 2):

The audio from the TV RCA outputs is stereo, but converting that to XLR will simply turn the 2 stereo channels into balanced lines (XLR is mono, one of the two lines is inverted then the two are mixed by the receiver) which will cancel each other out to a large degree.

Use an RCA cable with two phono-to-XLR converters (something like [this](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1023322-REG/kopul_a_xmrf_adapter_xlr_m_to.html)) and plug them into **two** of the mic/line inputs on your amp. You'll need to set both the inputs separately, but this will give you a true stereo input (true stereo output will depend on your amp's panning capabilities in any).